# Read asset file from an Android module

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I would like to know how to access the assets directory from android (file path)
I tried something like :

```
Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/Resources/sound/" + sound);
```

But it doesn't work !

I know that I could do that easily with Titanium BUT I need the URI file from the JAVA module ...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

No Uri or File class.

You have to use the assets manager and then open an inputstream for your file and read from the stream.